# Adding Event Listeners to <li> elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple drop down menu using CSS + JavaScript. I got the CSS part.

Now, I'm trying to add event listeners to the `li` elements that when clicked drop down into a sub-menu.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="expandable" href="#">More &#x25BE;</a>
                    <!-- <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Tuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Codes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lectures</a></li>
                    </ul> -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script>
        function expand() {
            console.log(this);
            /* Do something to display the drop down menu */

        };
        var anchor_arr = document.getElementsByClassName('expandable');

        for(var i = 0; i<anchor_arr.length; i++) {
            anchor_arr[i].addEventListener('click', expand, false);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As in above code, in the loop I'm adding the event Listener for click events on `li` elements with class `expandable`. But on clicking I get no output on the console.

Note: Solutions using Javascript only.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9g7py76g/

Comment: There are no `li` elements with class `expandable` in the code. The class is on the link inside the `li` element.

Comment: Everything looks right to me. In the console, it returns the element itself, not just text, so you might just be overlooking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```js
function expand() {
            
    if (this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display == 'block') {
        return this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'none'
    }
    this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'block'
};
var anchor_arr = document.getElementsByClassName('expandable');
for(var i = 0; i<anchor_arr.length; i++) {
    anchor_arr[i].addEventListener('click', expand, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="expandable" href="#">More &#x25BE;</a>
                     <ul class="sub-menu" style="display:none">
                        <li><a href="#">Tuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Codes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lectures</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Please note that I have added `style="display:none"` to the submenu `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to move your "`expandable`" class to the "`li`" element, instead of the "`a`" element as it is now, or you can change this line:

```
anchor_arr[i].addEventListener('click', expand, false);
```

by this one:

```
anchor_arr[i].parentNode.addEventListener('click', expand, false);
```

Comment: he is looking for attaching event to child of expand

Comment: @PranayRana I don't think so. His question says "Adding event listeners to <li> elements".